# How to: Create Python Application ON Windows For Mac OS

Tags: python, windows, macos, virtualenv, compatibility

I’d like to see your suggestions for, ultimately, writing a .py on a native windows machine that will run on a Mac OS as a .dmg file. Whether it’s using py2app in a virtual environment etc, besides partitioning HD and booting a Mac OS install.

Note: this is assuming all the modules used in the python code are Mac OS compatible.

Comment: This ultimately depends on what your Python code does... For example, do you need some compiled C library, which is machine-dependant (like numpy)? Simply `print("hello")` will work both on Windows and Mac

Comment: > besides partitioning HD and booting a Mac OS install; Oracle VirtualBox or VMWare Player then.

Comment: Or a docker container.